# How to persist current page during relaod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React application with a home or landing page and a dashboard, I want the dashboard components to persist after the page reloads, but whenever I refresh, it navigates back to my home page

AuthSlice

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authService from './authService';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
 
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  data:{
    user: {} 
  } ,
  loading: false,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: '',
  getcpd: null,
  employeeCode: { portalCode: '' },
  errors: null,
};

console.log('initial-redux state : ',initialState.user)

// Async thunk to initialize authentication state during application startup
export const initializeAuthState = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/initializeAuthState',
  async () => {
    console.log('checking local storage...');
    const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

    if (storedToken) {
      console.log('token present in local storage!');
      const decoded = jwtDecode(storedToken);

      try {
        const response = await authService.retrieveUserData(decoded.id);
        console.log('userData retrieved during initialization', response);

        // Return the payload to be used in extraReducers
        return {
          decoded,
          userData: response.data,
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during authentication state initialization:', error);
        throw error; // Propagate the error
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No token in local storage!');
      return null; // Return null if no token is present
    }
  }
);
 
export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/register',
  async (userData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      await authService.register(userData);
      return { success: true };
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

// Login user
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await authService.login(user);
      console.log('login response from service', response);

      if (response.token) {
        // Use jwtDecode directly
        const decoded = jwtDecode(response.token);
        console.log('decoded:', decoded);

        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', response.token);
        authService.setAuthToken(response.token);

        // Dispatch the setCurrentUser action using thunkAPI
        thunkAPI.dispatch(setCurrentUser({
          ...decoded, // Include the decoded token properties
          ...response.data, // Include additional user information from response.data
        }));

        // Return the response data
        return response;
      } else {
        console.log('Token is not available in the response data.');
        // Handle the absence of token, you may want to throw an error or handle it as needed
        throw new Error('Token is not available in the response data.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the error and return a rejected value using rejectWithValue
      const message =
        (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
); 

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCurrentUser: (state, action) => {
      console.log('setcurrentUser payload:', action.payload)
      state.isAuthenticated = !!Object.keys(action.payload).length;
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setUserLoading: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    resetErrors: (state) => {
      state.errors = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
    .addCase(initializeAuthState.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.data.user = {
        ...action.payload.decoded,
        ...action.payload.userData,
      };
    })
    .addCase(initializeAuthState.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.error('Error during authentication state initialization:', action.error);
    })
    .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
    })
    .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.errors = action.payload;
    })
  },
});

export const { setCurrentUser, setUserLoading, resetErrors } =
  authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Then I am importing initializeAuthState in app.jsx

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //Call initializeAuthState when the app starts
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(initializeAuthState());
  });

  useScrollToTop();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Router />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

My handleSubmit function for login

```
const handleSubmitLogin = async () => {
  // Dispatch the login action
  const actionResult = await dispatch(login(userLogin));
  
  // Check if the login action was successful
  if (login.fulfilled.match(actionResult)) {
    console.log('isAuthenticated:', isAuthenticated); // Add this line
    console.log('user:', user); // Add this line
  
    // If already authenticated, stay on the current page
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('Already authenticated, not navigating.'); // Add this line
      return;
    }
  
    // If not authenticated, navigate to the home page
    router.push('/home');
  }
};
```

and lastly my Route file handler

```
export default function Router() {
  // const { isSuccess } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const storedIsSuccess = localStorage.getItem('isSuccess') === 'true';
  const { isAuthenticated  } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { user  } = useSelector((state) => state.auth );
  const location = useLocation();
  const isReload = location.state && location.state.isReload;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && isReload) {
      // Prevent navigation away from the current page during refresh
      return;
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, isReload]);

  console.log(isAuthenticated && 'user authenticated');
  console.log('user before login starts',user);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          (user && isAuthenticated) ? (
            <DashboardLayout>
           
            <DashboardLayout>
              <Suspense>
                <Outlet />
              </Suspense>
            </DashboardLayout>
          ) : (
            <HomePage />
          )
        }
      >
```

I want user to be able to refresh a page and it doesn't return to home page.

Comment: Adding a return; inside a useEffect all it does is stop the useEffect from running its not a return to stop the rest of the component from running. also you have introduced a level of complexity by keeping home and dashboard on the same route i would consider breaking them into seperate routes and let react-router handle the complexity of routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

There are no navigation actions occurring in the app. The initial `isAuthenticated` state is `false` so when the page loads and the app mounts, `Router` conditionally renders the `HomePage` on the only route that exists, `"/"` on the initial render cycle.

## Solution

Start from an `undefined` initial `isAuthenticated` state value and conditionally null or some loading indicator while the `initializeAuthState` action processes and sets the `isAuthenticated` state based on the stored JWT token.

```js
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: undefined, // <-- we don't initially know auth state ‍♂️
  data: {
    user: {} 
  } ,
  loading: false,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: '',
  getcpd: null,
  employeeCode: { portalCode: '' },
  errors: null,
};
```

Update the `initializeAuthState` action to catch thrown errors and rejected Promises and return a ***rejected*** value from the Thunk.

```js
export const initializeAuthState = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/initializeAuthState',
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
      const decoded = jwtDecode(storedToken);
      const { data } = await authService.retrieveUserData(decoded.id);

      return {
        decoded,
        userData: data,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Update the auth slice reducers to handle both token check success/failure.

```js
...
.addCase(initializeAuthState.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.isAuthenticated = true;
  state.data.user = action.payload;
  state.isError = false;
  state.errors = null;
})
.addCase(initializeAuthState.rejected, (state, action) => {
  state.isAuthenticated = false;
  state.data.user = {};
  state.isError = true;
  state.errors = action.payload;
})
...
```

I suggest creating home route layout route component to abstract the auth check and conditional rendering of page content.

```
const Home = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated  } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return isAuthenticated
    ? (
      <DashboardLayout>
        <Suspense>
          <Outlet />
        </Suspense>
      </DashboardLayout>
    ) : <HomePage />;
};
```

```
export default function Router() {
  ....

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
        ....
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```